# How to achieve the following Image + Text in button in android app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make a clickable phone number button with an icon in my app. I was checking for some references and found google maps implementation good. How can I achieve this in my app?

I have tried the Image Button view but that does not solve the problem. I have put 'onClick' attribute for text & image views, but the button animation isn't there and both text & image icon does not look together.

Please guide me as to what view/s we have to use to achieve the result as in the image and how to get that animation on click of the button. Or is there any better way to achieve this?

I am aware of intents, so that part is clear.[image]

If you can let me know how to make that phone number copied to the clipboard automatically on hold of that button, that would be really great.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

Change spacing dimens according to your use and also change icon.

```html
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/callButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_download"
            android:tint="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amaranth"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_xxhuge"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:text="000 0000 000"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_70"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_large" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and set on click listener on `callButton`. use below code in java code.

And also i have added a code to copy phone number directly on click event. You have to `save text in clipboard`.

```html
LinearLayout callButton = findViewById("callButton");
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                  ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, text);
                  // You have to get text from phoneNumber textview. and set it to clipboard.
                  clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Think about the main layout where we have added each items having LinearLayout. I think you should use ContraintLayout.

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes we can use ConstraintLayout too.

Comment: @akshay i have also added a code to copy number on click event.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions:

- Do you have any experience with Android development?
- If so, do you have anything up and running?

I'm gonna assume you do have experience but you're asking before you start coding anything. There are many ways to implement this, the way that would be easiest would be to have a custom listview ([here's a simple and easy tutorial for that](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-custom-listview-in-android)) and use an item in the listview to display a phone number. Each listview item has a setOnItemLongClickListener which you can use and inside it use the ClipboardManager to copy or use an intent to the phone calling service.

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() { //list is my listView

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int pos, long id) {
        //Whatever you wanna do
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
});
```

Comment: I am learning android development on udacity and creating an app as a project in the curriculum. I will try this. Thank You for the solution, meanwhile if you can elaborate bit more that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want to achieve

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Your other layouts-->

    <TextView
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:text="The mobile number here"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> android:background="?selectableItemBackground"

This will add the default system animation of ripple(or anything) on click.
Also `android:focusable=" and android:clickable="true"` is necessary for this to work.
If you want to customize the click events, you better be using `selectors` in the background of your view.

For the 'Copy to Clipboard' feature you can refer to the other answers.

Happy Coding!

Comment: This made to achieve what I needed very easy. Thank you. Also, for the top & bottom lines in the image, I can use a blank <View/> or any other better way is there?-Regarding the attributes  android:focusable=" and android:clickable="true" where you said they are required for android:background="?selectableItemBackground", can you please mention how they are related and what they are doing or some best source where I can find a detailed explanation please

Comment: Glad this helped you! Yes for the lines you can simple use <View/>. Here's the definition from dev.android... for selectableItemBackground : "**_Background drawable for bordered standalone items that need focus/pressed states._**". The 'focusable' and 'clickable' attribs (as the name says) enables the views to react to the click events. More on this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)